# How can SwiftUI XCTest access ScrollView children?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, scrollview, xctest

We are trying to write an XCTest case for a SwiftUI application and are having a hard time locating children of scroll views.

Given this simple view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello")
                Text("World")
            }

            ScrollView {
                Text("Goodbye")
                Text("Cruel")
                Text("World!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the following XCTestCase fail to find the "Goodbye" element?

```
import XCTest
class ScrollViewUITests: XCTestCase {

    func testScrollChildren() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts["Hello"].exists, "Hello not there")
        XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts["World"].exists, "World not there")

        let scroll = app.scrollViews.firstMatch
        XCTAssertTrue(scroll.exists, "Scroll not there")

        XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts["Goodbye"].exists, "Goodbye not there")
        XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts["Cruel"].exists, "Cruel not there")
        XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts["World!"].exists, "World! not there")
    }
}
```

The text fields not embedded in the scrollview are located successfully. Running the app interactively shows the text fields onscreen. If the `ScrollView` is replaced with `VStack` then the test case will be able to locate the static texts.

This code targets iOS 13 with xcode 12 but we have tried targeting iOS 14 as well.

Comment: As a possible red herring or useful tidbit, we believe this test worked in iOS 13 / xcode 11 but have not validated that.

Comment: All tests passed. Xcode 12.0 / iOS 14.

Comment: I believe this might be specific to something - likely iOS 14.2? My environment is:
- xcode 12.0. (or xcode 12.2 beta)  
- platform: iOS 14.2 simulator  
- build target : 13.5

Comment: We verified that this test fails on iOS 14.2 simulator only. The test succeeds on iOS 14.1 and we assume it will work in 14.0 as well.

I think we can workaround for now and will try to figure out how to file a bug with Apple.